# Keeping a collection of SWT Widget objects

Tags: java, collections, widget, swt

I trying to use XML codes to create SWT Widgets.

I want to store these widgets first before adding it into the GUI component, so I created a List for storage of these widgets using

```
List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<Widget>();
```

However, how do I create this widget without specifying it's parent composite?

```
Widget newWidget = new Button(null,SWT.RADIO); // Argument cannot be null
```

In here, I do not want to add it to a parent composite yet, so I specify null, but I am not able to get through.

How can I create this Widget without adding to the parent composite (as I do not have a composite now)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as [javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.html) states, `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when `parent` argument is null. What you can do is place your widgets at some invisible composite, and then use `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setParent(Composite parent)` to add them to different Composite.